# Creating image using html5

Tags: html, canvas

I wanted to know if it is possible to create an image using html5.
Currently i am creating a text using canvas, now i want to convert that text into an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to save the canvas to an image file, you can use [Nihilogic's code](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/).

Use the [canvas text functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas).

For example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Canvas tutorial</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function draw(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('tutorial');
        if (canvas.getContext){
          var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          ctx.fillText("Sample String", 10, 50);
        }
      }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="draw();">
    <canvas id="tutorial" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If i am not wrong, the link specifies how to draw text in canvas. I want to create an image.

Comment: Oh, sorry. What do you mean "create an image"? Enable the user to save the image on his hard drive? Look at my updated answer, is that what you meant?

Comment: I don't understand, the user already sees that as if it was an image. What additional option you want the user to have, that makes it "as if it was an image?"

Comment: i just want to know if it is possible.

Comment: Chi-Lan, again, I don't understand **what** you're trying to do, so I can't really tell if it's possible or not.

Comment: Just a thought - no idea if it's of relevance and it is after all an old post but I think there is an issue of semantics here. Create an image versus drawing text in a canvas. Could it be that he/she wants to instead do more than write text in a canvas (so image)? I.e. even though what you've done is created an image they want to do more than just writing text?

Answer (score 0):

Create an image DOM element, and set the src to the canvas.toDataURL method.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);

function copy() {
 
       var image = document.getElementById("Img");
           image.src = c.toDataURL("image/png");


}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<img id="Img" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"/>
<button onclick="copy()">Copy</button>
```